# Recovering address from signed message in Elixir

Tags: web3js, ecrecover

I'm signing a message via Web3js:

```
const string = this.web3.utils.sha3("test");
const signature = await this.web3.eth.sign(string, this.wallet.address);
```

In Elixir, i'm parsing the hash and the signature
using `ExKeccak.hash_256/1` from [tzumby/ex_keccak](https://github.com/tzumby/ex_keccak) and
trying to recover the address using `ExSecp256k1.recover_compact/3` from [omgnetwork/ex_secp256k1](https://github.com/omgnetwork/ex_secp256k1) but it raises:

`{:error, :wrong_signature_size}`